# Firefox addon (extension) initialization on startup

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

We noticed that Firefox makes its first http requests before addons (extensions) are loaded and initialised.

In our case we use an extension to conditionally change useragent of the browser for some sites. This never works for the first site loaded upon the opening of the browser. For any consecutive sites (when the browser is loaded) it works with no problem. As workaround we keep the browser on at all times.

Is there any solution to this problem, to make Firefox load and initialise all extensions before making http requests?

Many thanks in advance for any hints, Tom.

Comment: I think this is possible by registering with `nsICategoryManager` I have never done it myself though but there artopic on stackoverflow that relate to this. `nsIContentPolicy` would be a thing to look into as well.

Comment: Thank you Noitidart. I will investigate it further.